# List all taxonomies with their descriptions

Tags: custom-taxonomy, list, categories

I have this snippet below that lists all my categories in linked hierarchical order and their descriptions. I was hoping someone could update it to allow for a specific custom taxonomy instead?

```
function list_cats_with_desc() {

  $base = wp_list_categories('echo=0&hide_empty=0&title_li=0&orderby=ID&order=ASC');

  // wp_list_categories adds a "cat-item-[category_id]" class to the <li> so let's make use of that!
  // Shouldn't really use regexp to parse HTML, but oh well.
  // (for the curious, here's why: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454 )

  $get_cat_id = '/cat-item-[0-9]+/';

  preg_match_all($get_cat_id, $base, $cat_id);

  // Let's prepare our category descriptions to be injected.
  // Format will be <a>category-name<span>category-desc</span></a>

  $inject_desc = array();
  $i = 0;
  foreach($cat_id[0] as $id) {
    $id = trim($id,'cat-item-');
    $id = trim($id,'"');
    $desc = trim(strip_tags(category_description($id)),"\n");   // For some reason, category_description returns the
                                                                // description wrapped in an unwanted paragraph tag which
                                                                // we remove with strip_tags. It also adds a newline
                                                                // which we promptly trim out.
    if($desc=="") $desc = " &bull; --- ";
    $inject_desc[$i] = '</a> <span class="cat-desc">' . $desc . '</span>';
    $i++;
  }
  // Now we inject our descriptions
  $base_arr = explode("\n", $base);
  $base_i = 0;
  foreach($inject_desc as $desc) {
    // We check whether there's an occurence of "</a>"
    while(strpos($base_arr[$base_i], "</a>") === false) {
      $base_i++;
    }
    // If we find one, inject our description <span>
    $base_arr[$base_i] = str_replace("</a>", $desc, $base_arr[$base_i]);
    $base_i++;
  }
  $base = implode("\n", $base_arr);
  echo $base;
}
```

Comment: why wp query was not used?

Comment: No idea, someone gave it to me like this.

Comment: So you want list of custom taxonomy with their description. am i correct? what kind of post your custom taxonomy is linked to?

Comment: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_list_categories/ you can pass the custom taxonomy as `$arg` to `wp_list_categories()`

Comment: The custom taxonomy is linked to a post

Answer (score 0):

This worked...

```
function list_cats_with_desc() {

  $base = wp_list_categories('echo=0&hide_empty=0&title_li=0&orderby=ID&order=ASC&taxonomy=CUSTOM-TAXONOMY-SLUG');

  // wp_list_categories adds a "cat-item-[category_id]" class to the <li> so let's make use of that!
  // Shouldn't really use regexp to parse HTML, but oh well.
  // (for the curious, here's why: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454 )

  $get_cat_id = '/cat-item-[0-9]+/';

  preg_match_all($get_cat_id, $base, $cat_id);

  // Let's prepare our category descriptions to be injected.
  // Format will be <a>category-name<span>category-desc</span></a>

  $inject_desc = array();
  $i = 0;
  foreach($cat_id[0] as $id) {
    $id = trim($id,'cat-item-');
    $id = trim($id,'"');
    $desc = trim(strip_tags(category_description($id)),"\n");   // For some reason, category_description returns the
                                                                // description wrapped in an unwanted paragraph tag which
                                                                // we remove with strip_tags. It also adds a newline
                                                                // which we promptly trim out.
    if($desc=="") $desc = " &bull; --- ";
    $inject_desc[$i] = '</a> <span class="cat-desc">' . $desc . '</span>';
    $i++;
  }
  // Now we inject our descriptions
  $base_arr = explode("\n", $base);
  $base_i = 0;
  foreach($inject_desc as $desc) {
    // We check whether there's an occurence of "</a>"
    while(strpos($base_arr[$base_i], "</a>") === false) {
      $base_i++;
    }
    // If we find one, inject our description <span>
    $base_arr[$base_i] = str_replace("</a>", $desc, $base_arr[$base_i]);
    $base_i++;
  }
  $base = implode("\n", $base_arr);
  echo $base;
}
```